# Включение одной функции если другая не используется больше определенного времени

Tags: c#, unity3d

Случай такой: если игрок нажимает на F персонаж стреляет и врубается определенная анимация, мне нужно что бы если игрок не нажимает на F больше секунды,то анимация переключается.

```
void Update()
{
 if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
 {
   Instantiate(bullet,bullet_spawn.position,bullet_spawn.rotation);
   an.SetBool("fire",true);
   //Здесь что-то должно быть,что бы было это:

   an.SetBool("fire",false);
 }
}
```

Comment: Добавить таймер или переменную, которая будет хранить время последнего нажатия. Если это время меньше нужного, то запуск одного метода, если больше то другого. Можно реализовать через DateTime и TimeSpan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться корутинами, которые умеют приостанавливать своё действие на определённое время.

```
    Coroutine _waitRoutine;

    float _waitDuration = 1f;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            if (_waitRoutine != null)
            {
                StopCoroutine(_waitRoutine);
                _waitRoutine = null;
            }

            Instantiate(bullet, bullet_spawn.position, bullet_spawn.rotation);
            an.SetBool("fire", true);
            //Здесь что-то должно быть,что бы было это:

            _waitDuration = StartCoroutine(WaitTimeRoutine());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitTimeRoutine()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_waitDuration);
        an.SetBool("fire", false);
        _waitRoutine = null;
    }
```

После выстрела запускается ожидание нужного времени, по окончании которого произойдёт установка вашего флага в аниматоре на false, а сама выполняемая корутина кешируется в переменную. Если новый выстрел происходит раньше, чем она закончится - мы останавливаем её выполнение.

Либо, вы можете использовать запоминание времени последнего выстрела, как вам предложили в комментарии

```
    DateTime _lastShoot;

    bool _isFire;

    float _waitDuration = 1f;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {

            Instantiate(bullet, bullet_spawn.position, bullet_spawn.rotation);
            an.SetBool("fire", true);
            //Здесь что-то должно быть,что бы было это:

            _lastShoot = DateTime.Now;
            _isFire = true;
        }
        else if (_isFire && (DateTime.Now - _lastShoot).TotalSeconds > _waitDuration)
        {
            _isFire = false;
            an.SetBool("fire", false);
        }
    }
```

В данном случае мы запоминаем время последнего выстрела, а так же сам факт того, что мы сейчас в состоянии выстрела, а не ожидания. После чего каждый кадр, если выстрела не было, проверяем в каком мы состоянии и не прошло ли необходимое нам кол-во времени для выхода из состояния выстрела.

Comment: DateTime в юнити для таких точных вещей лучше не использовать

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, почему?

Comment: DateTime используется для предоставления времени и даты, его точность не всегда подходит для игр и зависит от операционной системы. [Вот тут, например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343998/what-is-the-default-time-precision-of-datetime?rq=1), у человека ось выдала тик DateTime раз в 1/64 секунды, что кажется адекватной цифрой для игр, но представьте, что будет, если человек запустит игру в 128 fps или 256 fps. Опять же, в **данном случае** такой таймер все равно +- будет работать нормально. Но можно легко придумать случай, когда игровая логика сломается из-за этой неточности.

Comment: _Не хватило символов_. Даже тот пример не учитывает, что DateTime очень сильно зависит от процессорного времени и может выдавать разные значения при разной нагрузке системы. Да и не стоит забывать, что DateTime за собой тянет кучу чепухи в виде дней и лет, что нам в таймерах совершенно не нужно. В общем, для данной задачи DateTime никакой проблемы не составляет, но в целом это не очень хорошая практика и лучше использовать старый добрый `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` для собственных таймеров :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Я, обычно, накапливаю deltaTime, чтобы узнать сколько времени прошло) тут привёл этот вариант из-за того, что его упомянули в комментарии. Обычный использую т.к. чаще всего время таймера тоже должно растягиваться вместе с замедлением времени)

Comment: Не в обиду комментатору, но "игры" - это довольно своеобразная штука, поэтому лучше использовать встроенные в движок способы измерения времени. А так ответ хороший, + ;)